# Activity with two fragments showing different on screen rotation

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I have one activity with to fragments. I don't know how to make the layout so that they will be one under another in portrait orientation, and one next to the other in landscape orientation. Do I have to make two layouts and check the orientation in "onCreate" method and render the appropriate one? Or should I set the layout differently? (as it is now, it is ok in portrait view, but in landscape view they overlap).

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.apps.rucsi.biorhytm.MainActivity">

<fragment android:name="com.apps.rucsi.biorhytm.InputFragment"
    android:id="@+id/inputFragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<fragment android:name="com.apps.rucsi.biorhytm.OutputFragment"
    android:id="@+id/outputFragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

The result is in portrait:[image]

and in lanscape they overlap :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is happening here that you set your top fragment to align to the top of the parent `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and your bottom fragment to align to the bottom of the parent `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. You are just lucky on portrait that they fit.

You can do a few things set add this to the second fragment to tell it to be bellow the first fragment `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/inputFragment"`.

Or you could put them into a linear layout.

Comment: Well, I put them in a LinearLayout, and I set orientation vertical for portrait and horizontal for landscape. It's OK, But I have to use 2 layouts for this (ex. layout and layout_land) ? I can't figure it out how to make in a single layout to fit both situations.

Comment: you only need vertical orientation. If you rotate your phone the what is "up" will change too so you don't need a separate layout_land for this

Comment: yes, but in landscape I don't want the graph below, I want it in the right side of the form. With vertical orientation it aligns it below in landscape. I am sorry if I miss something, I am very new in Android development. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right I didn't read your post properly. Yes you need a landscape version too.